# How to detect the column separator of a CSV file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv

I've had several issues where CSV files that our board members uploaded weren't getting parsed correctly because of inconsistent format: comma-separated, semicolon-separated, tab-separated... Usually they didn't even know which separator had been used because Excel / LibreOffice Calc don't specify it when exporting to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

This function assumes that the CSV has at least 4 columns. It looks for the alternation of separators and non-separators in the file's first line (= usually the headers, which are unlikely to have extra commas or weird characters) and then returns the separator that is most common.

```
  def self.detect_separator(file)
    firstline = File.open(file, &:readline)
    if firstline
      separators = ",;\t|#"
      non_sep = "[^" + separators + "]+"
      sep = "([" + separators + "])"
      reg = Regexp.new(non_sep + sep + non_sep + sep + non_sep + sep + non_sep + sep)
      m = firstline.match(reg)
      if m 
        four_separators = m[1..-1].join('') # this line should have four separators but may have less if the data is less conclusive
        detected_separator = separators.split('').map {|x| [four_separators.count(x),x]}.max
        return detected_separator[1] if detected_separator
      end
    end
    nil
  end
```

Comment: A few notes: 1) `"[^" + separators + "]+"`  would generally be written as `"[^#{separators}]+"` (ruby favors interpolation over concatenation) 2) Given that this is intended to be a `Regexp` you can interpolate directly inside  `non_sep = /[^#{separators}]+/` 3) `|` has meaning in Regex so you probably want to escape that.

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin by constructing a possible CSV file.

```
arr = [
  ["abc", "d;ef", "hi;j", "k;l;mnp"],
  ["efg", "i;jk", "mn;p", "q;r;stu"],
  ["tuv", "w;xy", "zg;b", "c;d;e;f"]
]
```

```
FName = 't.csv'
```

```
require 'csv'
```

We will use commas to separate the columns<sup>1</sup>.

```
CSV.open(FName, mode='w', col_sep: ',') { |csv| arr.each { |s| csv << s } }
```

Let's look at the file we've created.

```
puts File.read(FName)
# abc,d;ef,hi;j,k;l;mnp
# efg,i;jk,mn;p,q;r;stu
# tuv,w;xy,zg;b,c;d;e;f
```

Now let's read this file, first with a comma as the column separator and then with a semicolon as the separator.

```
arr_comma = CSV.read(FName, col_sep: ',')
  #=> [["abc", "d;ef", "hi;j", "k;l;mnp"],
  #    ["efg", "i;jk", "mn;p", "q;r;stu"],
  #    ["tuv", "w;xy", "zg;b", "c;d;e;f"]]

arr_semicolon = CSV.read(FName, col_sep: ';')
  #=> [["abc,d", "ef,hi", "j,k", "l", "mnp"],
  #    ["efg,i", "jk,mn", "p,q", "r", "stu"],
  #    ["tuv,w", "xy,zg", "b,c", "d", "e", "f"]]
```

As expected, `arr_comma` is an array of three 4-element arrays. By contrast, `arr_semicolon`, contains two 5-element arrays and one 6-element array. Assuming empty strings are included for missing fields (e.g., `...ef;;gh;...`), this tells us that the file is consistent with a comma having been used as the column separator, but not a semicolon.

We could write a small method to check that each row has the same number of columns for a given column separator.

```
def sep_check(filename, sep)
  CSV.read(FName, col_sep: sep).map(&:size).uniq.size == 1
end

sep_check(FName, ',')
  #=> true
sep_check(FName, ';')
  #=> false
```

Note that CSV rows may contain quoted strings. If quoted strings contain the column-separator character they are not treated as column separators. Here's an example.

```
arr = [
  ["abc", "d;ef", "h\"q,r\"i;j", "k;l;mnp"],
  ["efg", "i;jk", "mn;p",        "q;r;stu"],
  ["tuv", "w;xy", "zg;b",        "c;d;e;f"]
]
```

```
CSV.open(FName, mode='w', col_sep: ',') { |csv| arr.each { |s| csv << s } }
```

```
puts File.read(FName)
# abc,d;ef,"h""q,r""i;j",k;l;mnp
# efg,i;jk,mn;p,q;r;stu
# tuv,w;xy,zg;b,c;d;e;f
```

```
sep_check(FName, ',')
  #=> true
sep_check(FName, ';')
  #=> CSV::MalformedCSVError (Illegal quoting in line 1.)
```

This is another condition that excludes a semicolon from being the column separator, but not a comma.

<sup>1. Including `, col_sep: ','` is optional, as the default value for `col_sep` is a comma.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
def column_separator(file)
    column_separators = [",", ";", "\t", "#"]
    max_separators = {}

    column_separators.each do |separator|
      max_separators[separator] = file.count(separator)
    end

    max_separators.max_by { |_, v| v }&.first
end
```